# Generating a procedural tiled background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a Shmup game with a tiled background, where I would like to make it procedure generated in the future.
But right now, I can't even make a static background. No matter what, I can't make the tiles fill the screen.

I'm using a tile of 64x64 pixels.

And here the code I'm using:

```
void Start()
{
    m_screenHeight = 1408;
    m_screenWidht = Camera.main.aspect * m_screenHeight;

    float UnitsPerPixel = 1f / 100f;

    Camera.main.orthographicSize = m_screenHeight / 2f * UnitsPerPixel;

    m_horizontalTilesNumber = (int)Math.Floor(m_screenWidht / TileSize);
    m_verticalTilesNumber = (int)Math.Floor(m_screenHeight / TileSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_horizontalTilesNumber; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_verticalTilesNumber; j++)
        {
            Instantiate(Tile, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(TileSize * i, TileSize * j, 0)), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what It look likes:

[image]

Seems to me that I'm having some problem converting my pixel coordinates to Units, or something like this.

Any tips or directions here would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the value of TileSize? it should be the same size as the texture. Also make sure the camera is set to orthographic.

Comment: @Imapler TileSize = 64 (pixels) and the camera is set to orthographic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this code below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tile prefab to fill background.
/// </summary>
[SerializeField]
public GameObject tilePrefab;

/// <summary>
/// Use this for initialization 
/// </summary>
void Start()
{
    if (tilePrefab.renderer == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("There is no renderer available to fill background.");
    }

    // tile size.
    Vector2 tileSize = tilePrefab.renderer.bounds.size;

    // set camera to orthographic.
    Camera mainCamera = Camera.main;
    mainCamera.orthographic = true;

    // columns and rows.
    int columns = Mathf.CeilToInt(mainCamera.aspect * mainCamera.orthographicSize / tileSize.x);
    int rows = Mathf.CeilToInt(mainCamera.orthographicSize / tileSize.y);

    // from screen left side to screen right side, because camera is orthographic.
    for (int c = -columns; c < columns; c++)
    {
        for (int r = -rows; r < rows; r++)
        {
            Vector2 position = new Vector2(c * tileSize.x + tileSize.x / 2, r * tileSize.y + tileSize.y / 2);

            GameObject tile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            tile.transform.parent = transform;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the whole demo project here: https://github.com/joaokucera/unity-procedural-tiled-background

Comment: I only had to add two more columns to fill the screen and worked like a charm.   int rows = Mathf.CeilToInt(mainCamera.orthographicSize / tileSize.y) + 2;